# Как узнать Generic Type у Java Interface

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть такой интерфейс:

```
public interface MyListener<T> { 
    void processor(String s, String s, T data);
}
```

Я делаю так `myListener.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()` эта строка возвращает мне полный тип  в таком формате `MyListener<java.lang.String>` 
я же хочу достать сам  `generic` тип `java.lang.String`

Каким образом я могу получить тип `<T>` с помощью `reflection`?

Answer (score 2):

Нашел вот такой способ

```
for (Type type : myListener.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()){
   if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
       ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType)type;
       System.out.print("Raw type: " + pType.getRawType() + " - ");
       System.out.println("Type args: " + pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
   } else {
       System.out.println("Type: " + field.getType());
   }
}
```